# Mercurial: permission denied error while ssh cloning

Tags: svn, mercurial, repository, tortoisesvn, clone

I am trying to clone a mercurial repository and see Permission denied error. 
The folder I am trying to clone the repository to has permissions to everything for everyone.

Here is the command and the output:

**%hg clone --verbose --ssh://user@hg.page.com/hg/folder "C:\FolderA\hg-folder**

requesting all changes

adding changesets

adding manifests

adding file changes

transaction abort!

rollback completed
abort: Permission denied
[command returned code 255]

  -

I also ran clone with debug option and noticed that before "transaction abort!" error it was adding zip files:
adding some_file/../file_name.zip revisions files: 249/10630 chunks (2.34%)

OS: Windows 7
Mercurial Version 2.8.1
TortoiseHG version 2.10.1

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in antivirus. After uninstalling it the repository has been cloned with no issues.

Comment: Which antivirus software may I ask?